# using chron package to format data in R

Tags: r, chron

at the moment I'm trying to convert a string into time-format. 
e.g. my string looks like following: `time <- '12:00'`.
I already tried to use the chron-Package. And my code looks like following:

```
time <- paste(time,':00', sep = '') time <- times(time)
```

Instead of getting a value like "12:00:00" the function times() always translate the object time into "0.5"
Am I using the wrong approach?

regards

Comment: I've used your code and it is correctly displaying as 12:00:00

Comment: what is the issue, can you update your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. If you check the 'class()' it is "times". However, if you want another way, try:

```
time <- '12:00:00'
newtime<-as.POSIXlt(time, format = "%H:%M:%S") # The whole date with time
t <- strftime(newtime, format="%H:%M:%S") # To extract the time part
t
#[1] "12:00:00"
```

Cheers !

Comment: No it din't work. So the hole story - I'm getting the time object from an html import but before I used the times() function I converted the object with as.character(time) and in dataframe the object is shown as "12:00"

Comment: What is the `class(time)` before doing `as.characther(time)` ?

Comment: It's listed as factor - but in the data.frame is shown as normal string..

Comment: I have two ideas: (1) try to write when you read the html if it is possible `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. (2) Else, the problem might be that you are trying to do `as.character` to the whole data.frame . Try it by columns. Tell me if the problem gets solved. Cheers !

Comment: To your second idea, I used this code segment:
for (i in 1:nrow(table)) {
  table$time[i] <- as.character(table$time[i])
  if(!is.na(table$time[i])){
    table$time[i] <- times(table$time[i])
    
  }
}
But this didn't worked

Comment: Can you provide with the document and how you read it ?, because I am confused. To me it works.